# does RhoMobile or PhoneGap or Mosync can work with SQL Server CE or SQLite database and does it work with barcode scanner manufacturer provided dll?

Tags: cordova, sql-server-ce, barcode-scanner, rhomobile, mosync

I am going to use RhoMobile or PhoneGap or MoSync framework to develop a mobile application taht will be deployed on device with Windows CE or Windows Mobile. This application should ready barcodes through its barcode scanner not the camera. The manufacturer provides C# and c++ dlls to use.

I need also that this application can read/write from a SQL Server CE database file, is it possible? Or the only way is to use database is SQLite?

Can those dlls be used with RhoMobile or PhoneGap or MoSync ?

Answer (score 0):

RhoElements, part of the RhoMobile Suite, includes support for hardware barcode scanners of Motorola devices. if the device you want to target is from a different HW vendor, you can implement a native extension using the C/C++ SDK provided by the HW vendor, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#native-extensions) or in [this recorded webinar](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1722).

Just as a remainder, RhoElements include a version of the WebKit rendering engine optimized for Windows Mobile and Windows CE devices.